# stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret) not resulting in error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

So I'm letting my user create a subscription with a free trial.

Node

```
const subscriptionWithTrial = async (req, res) => {
   const {email, payment_method, user_id} = req.body;

   const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    payment_method: payment_method,
    email: email,
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: payment_method,
    },
  });

   const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ plan: process.env.STRIPE_PRODUCT }],
    trial_period_days: 14,
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent', 'pending_setup_intent'],
   });

  res.json({subscription});
}

app.post('/subWithTrial', payment.subscriptionWithTrial);
```

React

```
const handleSubmitSubTrial = async (event) => {

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      console.log("stripe.js hasn't loaded")
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    const result = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      billing_details: {
        email: email,
      },
    });

    stripe.createToken(elements.getElement(CardElement)).then(function(result) {
 
    });
    
     if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
     } else {

     try {
      const res = await axios.post('/subWithTrial', {'payment_method': result.paymentMethod.id, 'email': email, 'user_id': auth0Context.user.sub});
      
      const {pending_setup_intent, latest_invoice} = res.data.subscription;

      if (pending_setup_intent) {
       const {client_secret, status} = res.data.subscription.pending_setup_intent;
    
       if (status === "requires_action") {
        stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret).then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            console.log('There was an issue!');
            console.log(result.error);
            
          } else {
            // The setup has succeeded. Display a success message.
            console.log('Success');
      
          }
```

I'm using card number `4000008260003178` so I'm pretty sure it's supposed to require authentication (which works) then result into `result.error` for insufficient funds on line `stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret).then(function(result) { if (result.error) {`. But this doesn't happen. Instead it gives me `console.log('Success');`

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. `stripe.confirmCardSetup` doesn't actually attempt to move money, it just sets the card up to do future off-session payments without needing 3DS.

Since you created your subscription with a 14 day trial, the actual first invoice payment won't happen till that's up. Meaning that in this case the test card is able to be set up correctly and won't see the payment failure till the trial period is up 14 days later.

Comment: "Meaning that in this case the test card is able to be set up correctly and won't see the payment failure till the trial period is up 14 days later". Will this happen in production? Will I need to collect a new payment when the 14 days is up in this case?

Comment: Yes that's possible regardless of whether you set up the card or not. Anything can happen to the card in 14 days, for instance it expiring or the card being replaced. You always need to be prepared to get your user back on-session to complete the payment.